# Prevent limit from removing older results unless page is refreshed

Tags: meteor

```
Posts.find({}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit: 3});

HTMl:
cat1
cat2
cat3
```

If a post is inserted this automatically becomes:

```
cat2
cat3
cat4
```

How could I prevent this from happening? I would like all results to stack unless the page is refreshed

```
<template name="temp">
<div class="posts">
    {{#each posts}}
      {{> cat}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In such situation you can use [Meteor.methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods).
Any time client side executes `loadLatestPosts` function then method `getLatestPosts` is asynchronously called and sends back data. Any updates on server side of collection Posts will not update client side. It means you have full control of updating templates but you lose reactivity.

Calling methods is asynchronous, it means you can only receive data within callback, so there is no option to return directly. That's why `Session` was used as a proxy.

### Client Side

```
<template name="latestPosts">
  <div class="posts">
    {{#each posts}}
      {{title}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

Template.latestPosts.posts = function () {
  return Session.get("posts");
};

var loadLatestPosts = function(){
  Meteor.call('getLatestPosts', function(error,arr){
    console.log(arr);
    Session.set("posts",arr);
  });
};

loadLatestPosts();
```

### Server Side

```
Meteor.methods({
  'getLatestPosts':function(){
    var arr = {sort: {date: -1}, limit: 3}).fetch();
    console.log(arr && arr.length);
    return arr;
  } 
})
```

Check source code here: http://meteorpad.com/pad/d25X95QC9DKRGW7ZC

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to use two queries in your template helpers.  One that gets new updates and one that gets 3 old posts.  Old posts must have a date before the template was created and new posts must have a date after the template was created.

The code below is untested but I think it is the common way to handle new data loading.  I am pretty sure that is how [telescope](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FTelescopeJS%2FTelescope&ei=n7f_U9jPCZCcugSGuoLQDg&usg=AFQjCNFSk0CYeDxYeZrYmOMAtDOlIKPErQ&sig2=5K3QS5mkz6-CAoTvn-2CtA&bvm=bv.74115972,d.c2E) does it if you need more examples.

So your template becomes:

```
<template name="temp">
   <div class="posts">
     {{#each newPosts}}
        {{> cat}}
     {{/each}}
     {{#each posts}}
        {{> cat}}
     {{/each}}
   </div>
 </template>
```

And the js becomes:

```
var createdTime;
Template.temp.created = function(){
  createdTime = new Date();
}

Template.temp.helpers({
  posts: function(){
    return Posts.find({date:{$lt: createdTime}}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit: 3}});
  },
  newPosts: function(){
    return Posts.find({date: {$gt: createdTime}}, {sort: {date: -1}});
  }
});
```